# Typescript issue with debugging "this" in VS2013 when using lambdas

Tags: visual-studio, lambda, typescript

I am converting some TypeScript code from using a hard-coded capture of "this":

```
var _this = this;

var querySucceeded = function(data){
    this.doSomething(data);
}

var test = this.executeQuery().then(function(data){
    _this.querySucceeded(data);
});
```

to using lambdas:

```
var querySucceeded = function(data){
    this.doSomething(data);
}

var test = this.executeQuery().then((data) => {
    this.querySucceeded(data);
});
```

TypeScript compiles the JS into something resembling the first code block and everything runs fine in the browser. The issue is when debugging in Visual Studio. When I inspect "this" after the lambda, it shows the window properties, instead of the class context.

If I debug directly in the browser, it shows the local context as it should. Is this a known issue? Maybe there is a problem with the mappings between the JS file and the TS file?

I am using VS2013 Update 4 and TypeScript 1.4.

Comment: It's a bug. Try here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+debug, and if it doesn't exist, open a new issue.

Comment: Thanks. I added it as a bug. [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2617](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2617).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inspect "this" after the lambda, it shows the window properties, instead of the class context.

Known issue. It's because the name isn't mapped. You will need to inspect "_this"